# How do I replace the extensions of filenames using regex in c++?

Tags: c++, regex

I would like to replace the file extensions from `.nef` to `.bmp`. How do I do it using regex?

My code is something like -

```
string str("abc.NEF");
regex e("(.*)(\\.)(N|n)(E|e)(F|f)");
string st2 = regex_replace(str, e, "$1");
cout<<regex_match (str,e)<<"REX:"<<st2<<endl;
```

`regex_match (str,e)` gets me a hit, but `st2` turns out blank. I am not very familiar with regex, but I expected to have something appear in `st2`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason why regex instead of (so much faster) straight string replacement?

Comment: May be I was not thinking out of the box, but I need to have it work - case insensitive, and on any complex file name like `abc.nef.nef`  and want it to end up as `abc.nef.bmp`. If I can do it with string replacement, I would. i'll read a little about it as well.

Comment: replace the last 3 characters with bmp?

Answer (score 1):

try this.

it will match .NEF or .nef

```
string str("abc.NEF");
regex e(".*(\.(NEF)|\.(nef))");
string st2 = regex_replace(str,e,"$1");
```

$1 will capture `.NEF or .nef`

[check here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3bR)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 string test = "abc.NEF";
 regex reg("\.(nef|NEF)");
 test = regex_replace(test, reg, "your_string");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use regex for such a simple task.
Try this function:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string Rename(const std::string& name){
    std::string newName(name);
    static const std::string oldSuffix = "nef";
    static const std::string newSuffix = "bmp";
    auto dotPos = newName.rfind('.');
    if (dotPos == newName.size() - oldSuffix.size() - 1){
        auto suffix = newName.substr(dotPos + 1);
        std::transform(suffix.begin(), suffix.end(), suffix.begin(), ::tolower);
        if (suffix == oldSuffix)
            newName.replace(dotPos + 1, std::string::npos, newSuffix);
    }
    return newName;
}
```

At first we find a delimiter position, then fetching the whole file extension (`suffix`), converting it to lower case and compare to `oldSuffix`.

Of course you can set `oldSuffix` and `newSuffix` to be arguments, not static consts.
Here is a test program: http://ideone.com/D09NVL

Comment: Why do you suggest not using a regex? Your code is not as readable as the regex code and it is longer.

Comment: @MarkusMayr Two reasons: performance and QA's knowledge of regex. The second reason is the main, actually. But it's just my imho, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I think boost offers the simplest and most readable solution with

```
auto result = boost::algorithm::ireplace_last_copy(input, ".nef", ".bmp");
```

Comment: Try it with `input = "Test.nef.is.not.at.the.end";`

Answer (score -1):

I think this

```
string str("abc.NEF");
regex e("(.*)\\.[Nn][Ee][Ff]$");
string st2 = regex_replace(str, e, "$1.bmp");
cout<<regex_match(str, e)<<"REX:"<<st2<<endl;
```

will work out better for you.